# Egit: How do I add a project from another computer to mine?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

My team and I are working on a project. 
I'm new to git. My friend set up egit on eclipse and created a repository. 
How do I get the project from that repository?

PS. We don't want to post our project online anywhere. We don't want to post it on github either.

Answer (score 0):

In the right bottom of the project page you can download the project as zip file.
you unpack it, and import("files" menu) it via eclipse.

in the settings of your project(github) you can set it to private or delete it, but i think the private setting needs you to pay.

alternatives could be an ftp server or perhaps a drop-box. but it won't be as easy to combine your work with that of the others.